# Use setInterval() with jQuery to change div content

Tags: javascript, jquery

Every 2 seconds, I want some content to change. At the moment, I have:

```
 setInterval(function() {
    $('.timer').text(3+3);
}, 2000);
```

However, it just replaces the current text of `.timer` with the number `6`. I want it to continue adding `3+3` to the existing number, so `6 + 3 + 3`.

[JSFIDDFLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/Xqnam/)

I'm using this as a learning exercise, so any additional help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

As `3 + 3 = 6`, that's no suprise, if you want strings, quote them

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('.timer').text(function(_, txt) {
        return txt + '3';
    });
}, 2000);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Xqnam/1/)

**EDIT:**

If you're trying to add numbers, you can do:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('.timer').text(function(_, txt) {
        return parseInt(txt,10) + 3;
    });
}, 400);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Xqnam/2/)

Comment: just about curiosity, what is this for ? `_,` first parameter in the function

Comment: Thanks, but how could I change the number of the div? So rather than append, add each value by 3?

Comment: @tmyie - If you're trying to add numbers, use numbers -> http://jsfiddle.net/Xqnam/2/

Comment: @Selman22 - The first argument is an index, I don't need that, so I used an underscore as I don't really need it for anything, but I have to type something as I need the second argument. I could have used i or anything else really, but an underscore is a reminder that I didn't really use it for anything.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I took it you want to add 3 to existing content. Here's the way to go

```
setInterval(function() {
    var oldContent = parseInt($('.timer').text(), 10);
    $('.timer').text(oldContent + 3);
}, 2000);
```

[Fiidle](http://jsfiddle.net/ehteshamkafeel/Xqnam/4/)

Comment: Thanks. What does the second parameter do, and is it required?

Comment: second parameter in parseInt specify the base and it's good practice to add it explicitly. In this case we want it in base 10.

Comment: I've also modified it, so it's `oldContent + 1`. However, `oldContent++` doesn't work. What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 0):

here is  [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZE7hc/)

```
var count=3;
setInterval(function() {
    $('.timer').text(""+parseInt($('.timer').text())+count);
    count+=3;
}, 400);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have specified 6 + 3 + 3 I guess your interested to add 6? 3+3 results 6 anyways?

```
setInterval(function() {
   var i = +$('.timer').text() ; // + converts the string to int
   i +=6; // add 6 as you have mentioned 3+3
   $('.timer').text(i); // update the inerText
}, 2000);
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/Xqnam/5/